# Characters admitted in DocReaders/DocAuthors fields

Tags: lotus-domino

Are there any limitation in characters that i can put in DocReaders/DocAuthors fields? Seems that "." character inside it create problems.

Comment: What are you putting in with a "." character?  You should be putting in an exact match for either a group name or a user's ID name in canonical form.

Comment: I've a Group in names called "XXX", where user "A" is member. If "XXX" is put in DocReaders field in a document, when "A" is logged, user "A" can see the document. With another Group "XXX.YYY", with user "A" in it as member, "A" can't see documents where "XXX.YYY" is put in DocReaders field

Comment: I recall issues in the past with the / character in group names, but not with the . character. Have you checked in the Document Properties dialog and/or NotesPeek to see what exactly is really stored in the DocReaders field? I'm wondering if it is interpreting the group name as if it were a username, turning it into "CN=XXX.YYY/O=YourCompany" or something else that would cause it to not match when it searches the Domino Directory for the group name.

Comment: No, group name isn't turned into canonical format

Comment: How many members are there in group XXX.YYY? And what happens if you create a new group, XXX.ZZZ, with only "A" as a member, and put that in the DocReaders field?

Comment: Good point, Richard. I'll make a test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuiding names views solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [Guidelines and restrictions for creating group names in Domino Directory](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21088877). The *period* ".", is a **valid character**.

Your problem must be elsewhere, maybe could you give us the real name of the group you're expecting problem with. Check also 64 chars max length.

Comment: Group name length is less than 64 chars

Comment: Lets double check the group name could you give us the XXX.YYY ?
Also make a Shift+Ctrl+F9 in your public names.nsf, to rebuilt all views.